# Why this works: Meteor-Blaze #with and data context?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I wonder why the following thing outputs 'hello' instead of 'bye'???

Template:

```
<template name="example">
    {{#with dataContext}}
        {{say}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Template Helper:

```
Template.example.helpers({
    dataContext: function() {
        return {
            say: 'bye'
        };
    },
    say: function() {
        return 'hello';
    }
});
```

(Meteor 1.1.0.2)

Comment: Try replacing {{say}} with {{dataContext}}

Comment: Yes, thx, but I ask why it works anyway? - just for curiosity.

Comment: You're saying IF data context == true, then render the result for "say". Now, I'm saying IF data context == true, then render the result for "data context".

dataContext will always returns true in an if statement, unless you specifiy return false.

You could write {{#with say}} {{datacontext}} {{/with}} and your output would be "bye".

Comment: [Understanding Spacebars](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/)

Comment: I don't get it - I ask myself why it works like it works. For my understanding my example should output 'bye' as the data-context sets say to 'bye'. But currently say within the data-context is set by the template-helper say ... this is conceptionally wrong for me.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest answer to this is the helpers have a preference over the data context.

If you rename one of them to something else it should solve your problem.

The order the lookup goes is:

1. The data context (if it contains a `.`). `{{say}}` does not.
2. The template's helper. `{{say}}` has a helper for `say`.
3. A template
4. A global helper such as those defined with `Template.registerHelper`.
5. The data context

So if the first isn't found, it goes down the list until it finds something

[1]https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/90b356061ff2464f11749dc8b43d1a139b233980/packages/blaze/lookup.js#L100-L139

Comment: Great simple explanation. I never really thought of it as an order of preference - always more of options, but you're right there is a system of hierarchy with contexts.